# How to get only the direct childs of the first element in an XML document?

Tags: java, xml

I am working on an XML example in order to understand DOM and XML better. I have a XML document with cars, of which I want to get the first cars-nodes.

I also want to do this generic, without giving a specific tag-name (find elements by tag "supercars" / "luxurycars" ...). More like "give me all the direct subnodes from cars" -> "supercars, supercars, luxurycars".

Therefore I've written the following code in order to understand the structure.

But the output confuses me:

- Why is the Nodelist length 7? Is it "[cars], [supercars], [content of supercars], [supercars], [content of supercars]"? I cant manage to get the elements out and see for myself.
- Why are there 4 empty "Current Elements:"?
- Why is the first NodeName "#text" and not "sportcars", which comes AFTER that?

**My XML document sportcars.xml.:**

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <cars>
        <supercars company="Ferrari">
           <carname type="formula one">Ferarri 101</carname>
           <carname type="sports car">Ferarri 201</carname>
           <carname type="sports car">Ferarri 301</carname>
        </supercars>
        <supercars company="Lamborgini">
           <carname>Lamborgini 001</carname>
           <carname>Lamborgini 002</carname>
           <carname>Lamborgini 003</carname>
        </supercars>
        <luxurycars company="Benteley">
           <carname>Benteley 1</carname>
           <carname>Benteley 2</carname>
           <carname>Benteley 3</carname>
        </luxurycars>
     </cars>
```

**My java file QueryXMLFileDemo.java:**

```
package xml;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class QueryXmlFileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("sportcars.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Node n = doc.getFirstChild();
            NodeList nL = n.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("Nodelist length: " + nL.getLength());
            for (int i = 0; i < nL.getLength(); i++) {
                Node temp = nL.item(i);
                System.out.println("Current Element: " + temp.getTextContent());
                System.out.println("NodeName: " + temp.getNodeName());
                System.out.println("Root Element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("supercars");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Nodelist length: 7
Current Element: 

NodeName: #text
Current Element: 
      Ferarri 101
      Ferarri 201
      Ferarri 301

NodeName: supercars
Current Element: 

NodeName: #text
Current Element: 
      Lamborgini 001
      Lamborgini 002
      Lamborgini 003

NodeName: supercars
Current Element: 

NodeName: #text
Current Element: 
      Benteley 1
      Benteley 2
      Benteley 3

NodeName: luxurycars
Current Element: 

NodeName: #text
```

So, how can I print only the nodes "supercars, supercars, luxurycars" and nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but I also have to admit, that my question was too broad and confusing. Therefore I post my way of solving the problem and hope, this clears what I was asking before.

```
package xml;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class QueryXmlFileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("sportcars.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document inputDocument = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            inputDocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Node carsNode = inputDocument.getFirstChild();
            NodeList carsNodeList = carsNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < carsNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node carTypes = carsNodeList.item(i);
                // hides the #text-entries
                if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE != carTypes.getNodeType()) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("CarType: " + carTypes.getNodeName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
CarType: supercars
CarType: supercars
CarType: luxurycars
```

So **without knowing the attributes** of my XML-document I can get the "first level" of the nodes - the first nodes within `<cars>`: `<supercars>`, `<supercars>` and `<luxurycars>`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of retrieving nodes is by using XPath or XQuery; inheritly easier to reason about

Comment: Thank you, I've looked into XPath and it seems to be better fitting for finding nodes in arbitrary XML-documents. Will use that in the future. For my problem this wont help, as I've tried to get more understanding of DOM, but a good hint nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You get the "#text" in the output because in XML there are text nodes between the elements, even if these are just white space like line breaks or indentation. See [the Node Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) on the different possible node types.

When you print a node's `getTextContent` it prints the node and its children, as [per the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29).

If you just want to ignore the #text nodes (or any other ones), you can check in your loop what node you're dealing with. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE != temp.getNodeType()) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it's still hard for me to understand the node types. How do I see the node type? Do I explicitly have to check the type before using it? Why did you know in your code example that you'd have to check for `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`?

Comment: Because it says in the Javadoc. :-) If you don't  want to check the node type with an if statement, you can use an XPath expression, but strictly speaking that just moves the check from an `if` to the XPath.